# DateTimePicker run different depends on api level in Android

Tags: android, date, datetime, timepicker, picker

I want to use Date Time picker in my project .

http://www.parallelcodes.com/android-datetime-picker-example/

This tutorial works perfectly. When I run this datetimepicker in api 19 showing like this web site and I want to do this.

When I run api 22 datetimepicker appear like this.

[image]

So, Any suggestions?

Comment: Use custom library, otherwise it will vary on different platforms.

Comment: you can use a custom theme so customize it with `new ContextThemeWrapper(myContext, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar)`

Comment: I use materialcalendarview https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Comment: If you are using the default widgets, then they will vary according to the different android versions. Better use  a custom widget for date picker or build a custom one yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code to solve this issue,

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private Calendar calendar;
    private Calendar maxCalendar;
    private Calendar minCalendar;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener;

    private static final String TAG = DatePickerFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    public void setup(Calendar calendar, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener){
        this.calendar = calendar;
        this.onDateSetListener = onDateSetListener;
    }

    public void setup(Calendar calendar, Calendar maxCalendar, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener){
        this.calendar = calendar;
        this.maxCalendar = maxCalendar;
        this.onDateSetListener = onDateSetListener;
    }

    public void setup(Calendar calendar, Calendar maxCalendar, Calendar minCalendar){
        this.calendar = calendar;
        this.maxCalendar = maxCalendar;
        this.minCalendar = minCalendar;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth, this, year, month, day);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        if(minCalendar!=null){
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
        }

        if(maxCalendar != null){
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
        }

        return dialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        if(onDateSetListener != null){
            onDateSetListener.onDateSet(view, year, month, day);
        }else{
            Log.w(TAG, "onDateSetListener callback is not initialized.");
        }
    }
}
```

and call like this ,

```
   public void showDatePicker() {


            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            fragment.setup(calendar, new OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                }
            });
            fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);

    }
```

Comment: How to call this in MainAcvtivity ?

Comment: I can't figure out   fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
But I will accept answer true ,thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is android own calendar which design changes for different API. If you want to use same calendar for all API version then you should try with a custom calendar rather then default calendar

If still have any confusion then please let me know